# How can I store invite requests in DynamoDB?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to write an invite system for a project I'm working on.  I plan on having a "give us your email address and we'll give you a beta invite when we're ready" type of thing.  I'm trying to figure out how I can design a DynamoDB table so that I can query for the first *x* users who haven't already received an invite.

The table I'm thinking about creating would have something like the following columns:

- email
- date
- fulfilled (boolean)

Can I do this with some combination of Hash keys, Range keys, and secondary indexes in DynamoDB?  Or is this something that's better suited for a SQL database?  The SQL query would be something like this:

```
SELECT email
FROM invite_request
WHERE fulfilled = 0
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here is to use the hash key as Fullfilled or Unfullfilled. That way you can use the query method which is much less expensive than scan. So your record would look like:

:Hash_key => Boolean , :Range_key => DateTime , Attributes => [email=>value]

Using this structure you can query all unfulfilled emails within a certain date range and limit the results. Hope this helps. If you want more access to the information for later you may want to look into SimpleDB as a better option, but if you're only using this for a single function Dynamo is a great way to go.